Novel with amnesiac soldier, limb regeneration and alien antigravity device
I am looking for the title of a scifi book, a novel I read in the early 1970s. It felt like between 1950s and 1970s in cultural, social mores, language, mindset, gender roles. A soldier wakes up with amnesia having regenerated a lost limb. He finds out it has happened before. This segues into somehow finding a weird alien machine (spherical or round) that might have to do with antigravity. Then he ends up on another planet (Mars) where I think there are multiple levels of evolution or species. There is of course a woman / love interest

The Beast by A. E. van Vogt, as identified in Playing with mental blocks; one-armed protagonist discovers an engine that spins and also Book about a one-armed cowboy who travels across time using a torus (sp?). In the UK it was published as Moonbeast, and that's the version I read.
Jim Pendrake is the soldier and he is missing an arm. He finds an alien motor and the field from the motor causes his arm to regrow in some undefined fashion. However the regeneration erases his memory - it turns out that any major trauma will heal but causes his memory to reset.
Pendrake is kidnapped by some organisation controlled by the president of the USA as his blood can now be used so heal and extend life.
Eventually he then finds himself on the Moon where he fights a Neanderthal and then a sabre tooth tiger, though I confess I have forgotten exactly how he got to the Moon.

Did you regenerate any limbs lately? :D

@JourneymanGeek How did you know I am actually a starfish? :-)

AE van Vogt had a habit of writing short stories or novellas then reworking them in larger novels, sometimes weaving multiple stories together. I'm pretty sure I've read this in both short story form and novel. See https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?14253

I first read The Great Engine in van Vogt's anthology Away and Beyond. For some reason I didn't encounter the other two stories until I read Moonbeast. I have to say I think is is one of van Vogt's less successful fixups. I was (and still am!) a big van Vogt fan, but like all authors not everything he wrote was great.
